# Change input value or add a new input if it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

*Background: I need to append certain data to post; similar to what jQuery's [`ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) does that for asynchronous requests except I need it for native form submits.*

I need to be able to add a couple of form fields to a form before it is submitted, but I want to make sure I don't add duplicate fields in case they're already there (i.e. original submit failed because of validation or something).

At first I thought something like this would be nice and coherent:

```
$("form").live("submit", function () 
{
    var $this = $(this);

    ($this.find('#stuff') ||
    $this.append('<input type="hidden" id="stuff" name="stuff" />'))
        .val('some value');

    // carry on with the native submit
    // this is actually correct, as opposed to $this.submit()  
    // which would create a loop

    this.submit();
});
```

Meaning *look for `#stuff`, if it's not found create it, then set its value to "some value"*. However because the result of the `.find()` is actually a jQuery wrapper, it would be implicitly converted to a `true` meaning that even if there are no matching elements found, the `.append()` code would never be executed.

Is there a nice way to tackle this whole *"look for an element and create it if it doesn't already exist"* scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep checking logic readable one would expand the conditional:

```
if ($this.find('#stuff').length) {
  $this.find('#stuff').val('some val');
} else {
  $this.append('<input type="hidden" id="stuff'" name="stuff" value="some val" />');
}
```

Alternatively one could just remove and re-add the element... I know, "dom operations are expensive" but if there are several fields to be operated on it's just so much prettier this way:

```
$this.find('#stuff', '#stuff2', ...).remove()
  .append('<input type="hidden" id="stuff" name="stuff" value="some val" />...');
```

Comment: you do loose any/all events associated with the elements though

Comment: @Josh: true, but not a concern in my case/for hidden inputs

Comment: I commented just for reference. i figure you posted a solution that works for you :)

Answer (score 2):

change `$this.find('#stuff')` to `$this.find('#stuff').length`

### edit

if you want to be able to all of it in one statement you can do

```
(
 ($this.find('#stuff').length && $this.find('#stuff')) || 
  $('<input type="hidden" id="stuff" name="stuff" />').appendTo($this)
).val('some val');
```

Comment: mmm... I wouldn't be able to `($this.find('#stuff').length || /*add #stuff*/).val('new value')` thogh, would I?

Comment: almost. `.val()` doesn't seem to work for when the input is being appended. If nothing else, this convinces me to use the less obscure if-else :)

Comment: just for fun. it could still work by reversing the selection IE `... || $('<input type="hidden" id="stuff" name="stuff" />').appendTo($this)`